# Как определить книжный формат для фрагмента?

Tags: android

В моем приложении одна активность-хост и несколько классов-фрагментов. С активностью все ясно: можно указать конкретную ориентацию в манифесте. А как быть с фрагментом, если один конкретный должен быть только в книжном формате, а все остальные предусматривают поворот экрана?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251930/allow-rotation-landscape-in-one-fragment